# Terraria: Broken Golden Pickaxe

Tags: terraria

When I crafted a golden pickaxe to mine some Crimtane ore down in a dungeon right under my house.
I went on a mining trip to get gold. (Also, I haven't found the merchant yet.. I've searched a lot..)
Anyway, I crafted my pickaxe and I get Broken Gold Pickaxe.. And I dont know why its broken or not.. I'm confused.

How Do I fix the broken part of my golden pickaxe?

Answer (score 2):

Your "Broken" pickaxe is just a regular Gold Pickaxe, with a prefix. It is (in every way) still functional. It just has a modifier called "Broken".

According to the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Prefix), the **Broken** modifier does the following:

> -30% Damage
>   -20% Knockback

This means that swinging your pickaxe will deal 30% less damage and 20% less knockback to enemies, when contrasted with a non-prefixed Gold Pickaxe.

---

As for "fixing" your Pickaxe (even though it theorically isn't fixing) - There are only two possible solutions to that.

1. Craft another Gold Pickaxe.
   *Modifiers are applied randomly when a new tool is made. There is also a chance that it has no modifiers. It was just that when you crafted your initial Gold Pickaxe, you were unlucky to get that modifier.*
2. Reforge it (using coins) by paying the Goblin Tinkerer to do so.
   *Although you'll be guarenteed to be given another prefix/modifier, it may not be a positive one.*

Comment: Actually, it is possible to get the same prefix back when reforging.

Comment: Can you play with me on terraria so I can find the merchant ??? I utterly need help.

Comment: @CollinEaton, could ask this as another question (even though you'll be very likely to be downvoted many times, and instantly). But I'll answer it: | **To get the Merchant, you must have at least 50 Silver coins in your inventory.**

Comment: Well I have like 1-2 Golden coins ...But the merchant hasnt shown.

Comment: @CollinEaton, then all you have to do is make sure you have an available housing room for the merchant... And then wait for him to spawn in.